# "Check for updates" Mac software - how to get the URL?

Tags: mac, updates

I would like to know how a particular Mac Application would check for the latest versions of software available .

"Check For Updates.." in the application menu contacts a URL. Is there a way to find out which URL its contacting . Would the URL to contact be stored in a file in my machine . Is there a way I can hide it from the user ?

I am not sure if this is a feature in the Mac OS SDK that is used by the developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some applications use [Sparkle](http://sparkle.andymatuschak.org/) for their automated updates. If they do, the Sparkle URL they contact is specified in the `Info.plist` file in the application bundle. Its key is `SUFeedURL`. It points to an (RSS? ATOM?) feed and looks something like this somewhere in the `plist` file:

```
<key>SUFeedURL</key>
<string>http://www.haystacksoftware.com/arq/arq.xml</string>
```

---

The URL to contact is (obviously) stored somewhere on your machine. Otherwise, how would your machine know what to contact for the update check?

---

Hiding makes no sense, since running a simple packet sniffer such as [Cocoa Packet Analyzer](http://www.tastycocoabytes.com/cpa/) will tell your users what your update status URL is. You can, of course, hard-code it in your binary so only advanced users (those capable of either using the `strings` command or running a packet sniffer) can find out your URL.